# How do I not show a selected record on a subform in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an access subform that shows a datasheet. The data in this subform is sorted by date, so the newest is at the top. To be user friendly I wanted the new record to show at the top of the list, instead of the bottom.  I found a way to accomplish this by putting a subform on top of a subform.  See here:

https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/new-record-at-top-of-continuous-form.103128/

I have formatted and placed the subforms, and it seems to work nicely, except one thing, both forms show a selected record.

[image]

Is there a way to have a datasheet subform not selecting anything when opened?

Is there a better way of showing the new record at the top of a list?

Comment: Try setting form AllowAdditions, AllowEdits, AllowDeletions to No. Of course, this will prevent any editing. Can use code to change these settings. I doubt will find any other method to show new record at top.

Comment: Alternative is code to set focus on new record row when form opens.

Comment: Both methods work as described, I just need to figure out which is the least annoying for users since this appears to be a limitation on Access.